# Is there any way to run a query after 30 mins in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, wait

I am coding a website wherein I will ban user for 30 mins after 3 tries however using setTimeout method doesn't seem to work here's my code:

```
let isOnce = true;
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    User.findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if (user.savedAttempts < 3) {
            passport.authenticate('local', {
                successRedirect: '/users/questions',
                failureRedirect: '/users/login',
                failureFlash: true
            })(req, res, next);
            attempts += 1;
            isOnce = true;
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (isOnce == true) {
                    User.updateOne({ email: email }, { $inc: { savedAttempts: 1 } }, (err, resp) => {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                    });
                }
                isOnce = false;
                res.redirect("/users/login");
            }, 1800000);
        }
    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: It would be probably easier to ban the user by setting `user.bannedUntil = new Date().getTime() + 1800000; ` and save that to the db. Then when the user tries to login check if not banned.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think your understanding of setTimeout is correct. What it does is it execute the function after a certain time period

A better way to implement what that behavior is to store the timestamp of his 3rd try, and compare it against Date.now() to check if the 30 minutes ban period has passed

Comment: thank for your advice it's now working but I have another question I supposed to give 3 tries but since it's a post request I have an extra try that doesn't do anything can you give me an advice on that as well? Thank you